# Making sys.config file dynamic by passing argument to erl -config <file_name> [args]

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell, erlang-supervisor

In the below erl command I want to pass config file along with the arguments.

`erl -config sys.config [Args]`

Answer (score 0):

The correct command line would be

```
erl -config sys [Args]
```

without the .config extension, which is added automatically.